# Search queries per user session in Google Analytics

Tags: session, google-analytics, filtering

We have a WordPress site that has a site search. The results page for this search have the URL of mysite.com/?s=search+term , just like the standard WordPress setup.

What I'm curious about is how to find out if a *specific* user searched for more than one term in a particular session.

Would there be a way to filter all page views by the existence of the "?s=" in the URL, and then filter those by any that occured in the same session?